# KIF or Frank for Automated iOS device testing

Tags: ios, ruby, cucumber, frank, kif

Looking for advice from someone who has tried both. We have a good chunk of our framework in Ruby, so Frank with Cucumber looks like an obvious choice. How well does Frank send tests to actual devices?

Comment: I found KIF to be more useful for my needs than Frank.. some details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17289283/766570)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know guys that have setup both Frank and Kif, and Kif is much easier to setup with physical devices.  However; Frank does provide this ability, as described at http://testingwithfrank.com/device.html.